# SwingWorker done() method throws nullpointerexception with get()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I've written a swing worker with the job of computing some text-statistics and afterwards updating a GUI element in the EDT with the results.
After some experimenting I found out that you should manipulate the GUI only in the `done()` method, not in the `doInBackground()`. In order to achieve that I remodeled the worker to have a return value `String[]`, which I should be able to grab with `get()`.
Apart from some `publish()` methods you might find some bad calls from the `doInBackground()` method manipulating the GUI directly, and if you think that my problem might be caused by that - let me know.

```
package my.worker;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import my.tools.CountKeywords;
import my.tools.FilterStopwords;
import my.tools.KeywordSuggestion;
import my.tools.RelevanceRanking;

public class ProcessDatabaseWorker extends SwingWorker<String[], String> {

    private final JLabel debugJLabel;
    private final JLabel infoJLabel;
    private final JLabel warnJLabel;
    private final JLabel errorJLabel;
    private final JLabel infoboxJLabel;
    private final String databaseString;
    private final JProgressBar jProgressBar;
    private final JComboBox keywordJComboBox;
    private int percent;
    private int index;

public ProcessDatabaseWorker(JProgressBar jProgressBar, String databaseString,
            JLabel debugJLabel, JLabel errorJLabel, JLabel warnJLabel,
            JLabel infoJLabel, JLabel infoboxJLabel,
            JComboBox keywordJComboBox) {
        this.percent = 1;
        this.jProgressBar = jProgressBar;
        this.databaseString = databaseString;
        this.debugJLabel = debugJLabel;
        this.errorJLabel = errorJLabel;
        this.infoJLabel = infoJLabel;
        this.warnJLabel = warnJLabel;
        this.infoboxJLabel = infoboxJLabel;
        this.keywordJComboBox = keywordJComboBox;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        FilterStopwords fs = new FilterStopwords();
        CountKeywords ck = new CountKeywords();
        RelevanceRanking rr = new RelevanceRanking();
        HashMap<String, Integer> nKeywords = new HashMap();
        Map<String, TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>>> keywordsPerDocument = new HashMap();
        String replace = databaseString.toLowerCase();
        String splitter = ("\\n");
        String[] documentLines = replace.split(splitter);
        int N = documentLines.length;
        publish("Stopworte werden gefiltert...", "10");
        String[] completeFilteredText = fs.filterStopwords(replace);
        publish("Keywords werden gezählt...", "20");
        HashMap<String, Integer> completeKeywords = ck.countKeywords(completeFilteredText);
        index = 0;
        percent = 1;
        final double oneLinePercent = N / 100;
        final double oneKeywordPercent = completeKeywords.size() / 100;
        completeKeywords.forEach((String key, Integer value) -> {
            int n = 0;
            key = String.valueOf(key).trim();
            for (String line : documentLines) {
                String[] lineWords = line.split(" ");
                for (String word : lineWords) {
                    word = word.trim();
                    if (word.equals(key)) {
                        n++;
                        nKeywords.put(key, n);
                    }
                }
            }
            index++;
            if (index == oneKeywordPercent) {
                percent++;
                publish("Zählung...", String.valueOf(percent));
                index = 0;
            }
        });
        publish("Keywords werden geranked...", "40");
        index = 0;
        percent = 1;
        for (String documentLine : documentLines) {
            TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> rankedKeywords;
            String[] lineFilteredWords = fs.filterStopwords(documentLine);
            HashMap<String, Integer> keywords = ck.countKeywords(lineFilteredWords);
            rankedKeywords = rr.rankKeywords(keywords, lineFilteredWords, N, nKeywords);
            keywordsPerDocument.put(documentLine, rankedKeywords);
            index++;
            if (index == oneLinePercent) {
                percent++;
                publish("Ranking...", String.valueOf(percent));
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        publish("Keyword-Vorschläge werden generiert...", "70");
        KeywordSuggestion ks = new KeywordSuggestion();
        TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> keywordSuggestionsTree = ks.keywordSuggestion(keywordsPerDocument);
        String[] keywordSuggestionsArray = new String[keywordSuggestionsTree.size()];
        index = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        double onePercent = keywordSuggestionsTree.size() / 100;
        percent = 1;
        publish("Keyword-Vorschläge werden generiert...", "75");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : keywordSuggestionsTree) {
            double round = round(entry.getValue(), 2);
            keywordSuggestionsArray[index2] = round + " - " + entry.getKey();
            index2++;
            index++;
            if (index == onePercent) {
                percent++;
                publish("Keywords...", String.valueOf(percent));
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        keywordJComboBox.removeAllItems();
        for (String entry : keywordSuggestionsArray) {
            publish("Keyword-Vorschläge werden befüllt...", "80");
        }
```

This is the line returning the value I need for the get()...

```
        return keywordSuggestionsArray;
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<String> s) {
        infoboxJLabel.setText(s.get(0));
        jProgressBar.setValue(Integer.valueOf(s.get(1)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
```

Here's the point where the NullPointerException is thrown...

```
            String[] get = get();
            for (String entry : get) {
                keywordJComboBox.addItem(entry);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcessDatabaseWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        publish("Verarbeitung der Daten abgeschlossen!", "100");
    }
}
```

**For further information here's the complete trace:**

```
Apr 14, 2016 10:40:06 AM my.worker.ProcessDatabaseWorker done
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:602)
    at my.worker.ProcessDatabaseWorker.done(ProcessDatabaseWorker.java:197)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:737)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:832)
    at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:842)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.logfileanalyzer.LogFileAnalyzerGUI.keywordJComboBoxItemStateChanged(LogFileAnalyzerGUI.java:830)
    at my.logfileanalyzer.LogFileAnalyzerGUI.access$2400(LogFileAnalyzerGUI.java:48)
    at my.logfileanalyzer.LogFileAnalyzerGUI$15.itemStateChanged(LogFileAnalyzerGUI.java:329)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(JComboBox.java:1352)
    at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
    at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:174)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeAllItems(JComboBox.java:771)
    at my.worker.ProcessDatabaseWorker.doInBackground(ProcessDatabaseWorker.java:165)
    at my.worker.ProcessDatabaseWorker.doInBackground(ProcessDatabaseWorker.java:43)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now, for my question: which part of the worker didn't I use correct or where did I go wrong with my program-logic? As you can see i am pretty new to programming with swing workers and threads in general, so I'm sure there is a simple solution for a simple mistake caused by inexperience.

Furthermore, let me know, if any other parts of my program are needed, in order to paint a better picture about what's going on.

EDIT: error was exactly where user Moh-Aw described - edited my code as following fixing it:

```
private void keywordJComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
        if (keywordJComboBox.getItemCount() != 0){
            if (!((String) keywordJComboBox.getSelectedItem()).equals("")) {
                String selected = (String) keywordJComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                String[] blubb = selected.split(" ");
                searchJTextField.setText(blubb[2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Concerning the possible duplicate - i'm pretty sure that this post is. I honestly thought it was a wrong implementation of `swing workers`, not something as simple as it actually was - so this post may as well be closed ^^

Comment: Do you start your SwingWorker on itemStateChanged of a ComboBox? If so, please post that part.

Comment: You can remove the edit again as it is of no help. Instead post the method `keywordJComboBoxItemStateChanged()` of your `LogFileAnalyzerGUI` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is line 830 of your `LogFileAnalyzerGUI` class. The `itemStateChanged()` method of your `keywordJComboBox` is causing a `NullPointerException`

This method is triggered by your `ProcessDatabaseWorker` at `keywordJComboBox.removeAllItems()`

By removing all items the `ItemState` changes to DESELECTED.

The method `itemStateChanged()` runs again, but no more items are in the `ComboBox` thus causing the NPE.